# Passing view controllers to each other or making sure to init them only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

The situation I find myself in is as follows.

In the AppDelegate I need to be able to access an SKView which I'm creating in a later view controller so that I can pause the SKView when entering the background. The only way I know of being able to do that is to create the SKView within the AppDelegate and then set it within the view controller I use later as a property. The downside is that, that view doesn't exist for me to set anything on until it's created first. So as a result I'm doing the following.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKView *skView;
.
.
.
self.skView = [[SKView alloc] init];
SceneViewController *svc = [[SceneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[svc setSkview:self.skView];
```

Within SceneViewController I have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet SKView *skview;
```

The questions I have are, should I really have strong set at all on a property that is an IBOutlet? And also is there a better way than this to do what I'm doing.

I am also passing the SceneViewController to another view controller in the same manner so that it can also get a reference to it to allow it to present the view at the appropriate time. I think the answer to the above issue will help with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not listen for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` in your view controller that owns the `SKView` and pause on that?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use **delegates** to communicate between 2 view controllers instead of keeping reference with each other see this for coordination view controllers...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Make singleton to insure only one instant of class.

```
+(SKView *)singleton 
{
    static SKView *shared = nil;

    if(shared == nil) 
    {
        shared = [[SKView alloc] init];
    }

    return shared;
}
```